# Cancel the waiting of a task using a timer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function `someLongRunningFunction()` that can take a while. I have a timer of 1 second. I want to cancel the waiting for the long running function so I can continue after `timedTask.value`. Here is my code:

```
let timedTask = Task {
  try await someLongRunningFunction()
}

let timer = Timer(
  timeInterval: 1,
  repeats: false
) { _ in
  timedTask.cancel()
}
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .default)

do {
  _ = try await timedTask.value
} catch {
  // This doesn't get called
}
// Doesn't continue past here
```

This doesn't work, because although cancel is called, it still waits for `timedTask.value`. Note that `someLongRunningFunction()` doesn't get cancelled. How do I do this?

Update:
Here is what `someLongRunningFunction()` looks like.

```
func someLongRunningFunction() async throws -> Output {
  if Task.isCancelled {
    throw MyError.cancelled
  }
  return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    var finishedWithoutValue = true
    cancellable = myPublisher
      .first()
      .sink { result in
        switch result {
        case .finished:
          if finishedWithoutValue {
            continuation.resume(throwing: MyError.cancelled)
          }
        case let .failure(error):
          continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        }
        cancellable?.cancel()
      } receiveValue: { value in
        finishedWithoutValue = false
        continuation.resume(with: .success(value))
      }
  }
}
```

This takes the first value of a Combine publisher and returns it. This essentially turns Combine into async/await. However, this does not respond to being cancelled by a Task. How can I do that?

Comment: Calling [cancel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/cancel()) requires support from the Task block.  In other words, it is up to your code in `someLongRunningFunction` to check if it has been cancelled and return early if possible. Cancel is not preemptive; it will not "force" code to stop.  Are you looking for [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:))?

Comment: I see, I've updated my code to show you what `someLongRunningFunction` is - it's essentially turning combine into async/await but doesn't support cancellation. How can I make it support that? I don't think the taskCancellationHandler would be suitable because I need to propagate the error up and continue afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn a Combine publisher into an asynchronous stream using the `.values` computed properly and you'll get cancellation for free:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

@main
enum App {
    static func main() async throws {
        let publisher = (0..<10).publisher
            .delay(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        
        let observeTask = Task {
            for await value in publisher.values {
                print(value)
            }
        }
        
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2.0))
        observeTask.cancel()
        _ = await observeTask.result
    }
}
```

Here, there is a publisher which publishes integers every half a second. There are two tasks: the first one (`observeTask`) uses an async for-loop to observe the successive values, and the other one (the top level task) waits few seconds and then cancels the observation task. If you run the code you'll see that the observation ends right when the `.cancel` is called.

I think you can adapt your code to use this pattern and then cancellation using a timer should be much simpler. Here is how the `longRunningFunction` could look like:

```swift
func longRunningFunction() async throws -> Int {
    let values = Just(42)
        .delay(for: 5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .values
    
    var iterator = values.makeAsyncIterator()
    let value = await iterator.next()
    
    guard let value = value else {
        print("Cancelled")
        throw MyError.cancelled
    }
    
    return value
}
```

And this is how you would cancel the task after a timeout:

```swift
@main
enum App {
    static func main() async throws {
        let observeTask = Task {
            let value = try await longRunningFunction()
            print(value)
        }
        
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2.0))
        observeTask.cancel()
        _ = await observeTask.result
    }
}
```